# ORACLE DB ERROR

Tags: oracle, error-handling

We are currently experiencing a problem with Oracle DB 8. It is no longer starting and we get this message:

ERROR at line 1:
ORA-01113: file 19 needs media recovery
ORA-01110: data file 19:
'E:\ORACLE\PRODUCT\ORA8\DB_1\DBS\ORADATA\MED\CCI_DATA.ORA'

Any help is appreciated

Comment: Is your database in `ARCHIVELOG` mode?  How do you do backups?  What is the most recent backup that you have?  Do you need the data in the tablespace with this data file (presumably the `CCI_DATA` tablespace)?  Do you need the data since the last backup?

Answer (score 2):

Looking at the paths of the datafile, I assume/hope this is no production database. If this database is setup as a regular production database, it is running archivelog mode. In that case it is quite simple to recover, if you have a valid backup for the damaged datafile[s], including all archived logfiles created since the start of that backup.

restore the datafile[s] effected
recover the database
open the database.

Oracle still has the docs for this ancient release online. Check [Oracle8i Backup and Recovery Guide](http://docs.oracle.com/cd/A87860_01/doc/server.817/a76993/toc.htm) for the details.

After that, upgrade to a current release. My guess is that many dbas have never had training on this release .... I think having a good dba at hand could be helpful...

Answer (score 1):

recover database;

when it asks for an archivelog file, put in the path and name of one of your redologs. If that one doesn't work, try another redolog. Keep it going until you run out of redologs  ;-)

If that didn't work, try to recover from your last cold backup and roll it forward to a point in time prior to you taking the database down. If you didn't have a cold backup (and spank your fingers if you don't take periodic cold backups), try to do a point in time: set the date/time to 5 minutes before the issue cropped up (or when the database croaked).

I have had success recreating the database with a new controlfile. Sometimes, you can clear a controlfile issue this way.

During these processes, if one works, you may have to recover data from before the issue cropped up. Better to lose 1 hour of Production processing than the entire database!